# nodejs return from async function (sighs, again i know)

Tags: node.js

Please be advised that this topics is not trivial for beginners, even reading older posts.

So I wrote a small Node.Js application where a function in the main application calls another function on a custom module. This function uses a callback, but I need a callback to the callback.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
// file sample.js
function foo(param, callback) {
    request.get({
        url: <url>
        headers: {<headers>}
    }, (err, response, data) => {
        array = []
        obj.forEach(function (entry) {
               // do stuff with array
            };            
        });
        callback(null, array);
    });
}
module.exports.foobar = foo;
```

Then on my `app.js` file, I'm calling function `foo` multiple times like this:

```
// file app.js
function bar(err, data) {
    //do things with data
    }    
}
var param = 'some param';
foo(param, bar);

param = 'some other param';
foo(param, bar);
```

but i want to use `data` (a `json` obj) outside the `bar` function, like assign it to different variables. Do I make another callback inside `bar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
function foo(param, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get({
        url: '',
        headers: {}
    }, (err, response, data) => {
        array = []
        data.forEach(function (entry) {
            // do stuff with array
        });
        resolve(array)
    });
  })
 }
 module.exports.foobar = foo;
```

get resolve data

```
let param = 'some param';
foo(param).then(data=>{
  // get your data here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and their related concept async/await, exist exactly for this purpose. Callbacks can get overly-nested if you're not careful, and this approach makes it simpler to flatten them down to one level. Both are standard in node 8 (stable).

Callbacks and promises are different patterns to do the same thing, and are compatible enough that you can simply wrap [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) around your existing callback.

```
const util = require('util');
const barAsync = util.promisify(bar);

// Wrap in an IIFE to get async support
(async () => {
  let data = await barAsync('some param');
  // do things using data...
  data = await barAsync('some other param');
})();
```